# print each row in different pages

Tags: c#, activereports

I have a data table with data rows, which is coming from Ultra grid. I want to print each row in different pages of the report. How do I achieve this. I am using C# and active report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print each row on a new page in ActiveReports, look at the properties of the `detail` section of your report. The `NewPage` property should be set to `After`. Each row in your report will now print on its own page.